# React Material UI ExpansionPanel Remove Borders

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React Marterial UI library in various places in my project. Now I've added there ExpanelPanel component (https://material-ui.com/components/expansion-panels/) in my project too.

I'm trying remove the default border that this component has like this:

```
import MuiExpansionPanel from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanel';
import MuiExpansionPanelDetails from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelDetails';
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";

const CustomMuiExpansionPanel = withStyles(
    {
        root: {
            padding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderRadius: 0,
            borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
            margin: 0
        },
        expanded: {
            padding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderRadius: 0,
            borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
            margin: 0
        }
    }
)(MuiExpansionPanel);

const CustomMuiExpansionPanelDetails = withStyles(
{
        root: {
            padding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderRadius: 0,
            borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
            margin: 0
        },
        expanded: {
            padding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderRadius: 0,
            borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
            margin: 0
        }
    }
)(MuiExpansionPanelDetails);
```

However, it doesnt seems to be working, the border is still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see, MaterialUI expansion panel borders come from MuiPaper box-shadow property.

You can try

```
boxShadow: "none"
```